# Rebinding Observable collection wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I created a WPF window to bind data in Datagrid based on the selection of date by the user.BY default it loads for a specific date which works fine. But When the date is changed, the grid is showing empty rows.but the observable collection I used is having data. The observable collection is of DataTable type.

Note: I used to set itemsource=null when there are no records since I am using the same grid for 2 different tables based on a radio button check.

I have set the public variable as Binding variable in the XAML, used INOtifyChanged interface.

My issues is when the same collection reloads, the Datagrid failed to bind and shows empty rows but generating columns. When the previous attempt set the itemsource as null, the current loading failed to load the column also.

Any generic scenario, I am facing,? Please help

My Code:

```
private ObservableCollection<DataTable> custInfoCol = new ObservableCollection<DataTable>();

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

private DataTable _CustInfo;

public DataTable CustInfo
{
    get { return _CustInfo; }
    set
    {
        _CustInfo = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CustInfo"));

    }
}

private void rbPrev_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    custInfoCol.Clear();
    custInfoCol.Add(CustInfo = showcustomer(cid));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue which is very simple. I had created the datatable instance as global and i changed it to local just before loading the executereader() method.It resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might need to change the UpdateSourceTrigger in your binding:

```
Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=Day, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

I've had problems with the default behavior of it before, so now I just type it out every time.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I have added the UpdateSourceTrigger in DG Itemsource.. should i change it to Height property you mean?

Comment: nope, I just didn't have any of ur code to go by so I just grabbed a line from my own code

Comment: <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding custInfo,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"

This is how my XAML looks like

Comment: Yes, it didnt worked.. I have posted my sample code in the Question

Answer (score 0):

Based on this piece of code you provided in the comment:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding custInfo,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
```

I think there is typo in the Xaml. You should use `... Binding CustInfo...` with capital *C*.

Of course, if `AutoGenerateColumns` is true, then I guess this is not the problem, because you wrote

> Datagrid failed to bind and shows empty rows but generating columns

Which the Binding works. Therefore, you need to check `showcustomer(cid)` and make sure it contains the required `DataRow`s.

Comment: Hey, Ron. That was a typo when in pasted the code here.. It is fine in the original code and AutogenerateColumn is also true. The DataTable is not empty whenever it reloads, but still not showing it in the grid.